# imported non spendable btc

Tags: transactions

Good day.

I have a slight issue! A friend of mine has imported a few wallets to his main wallet. All the imported wallets has "Non Spendable Bitcoin" in them ranging from $2-$45k respectively. Is there any way i can retrieve them via finding the private keys for them to make the btc coins spendable again? Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can’t, as far as the system is concerned the money isn’t yours.

Comment: People reporting problems with "non-[spendable](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=spendable+is%3Aq) Bitcoin" (or "[watch-only](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=watch-only+is%3Aq)" addresses/wallets) on this website and also seeking private-keys are, so far as I know, invariably victims of fraud.

Answer (score 2):

Impossible unless you have the private key belonging to the adress.

Your friend didn't import a few "wallets", he imported a few adresses, which makes his wallet a "[Watch-Only](https://bitcoin.org/en/glossary/watch-only-address) wallet" (for the adresses that were imported.)

> Is there any way i can retrieve them via finding the private keys for them to make the btc coins spendable again?

Again, if you only have a public key, master public key, or adress format, the answer is no.

If you have a seed / private key from which the (imported) address xpub/public key was originally derived from, then yes, you could recover his funds.

Edit: I feel like we're missing a whole lot of context here: Did your friend buy these "wallets"? If so- he most likely got scammed.